# В каком файле в проекте IntellijIdea лежит понимание того, где ресурсы, а где исходный код?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, проект

Предположим я скачал проект с гитхаба, собранный на maven.  Первые мгновения после запуска директория с исходником помечена как обычная папка, а спустя несколько мгновений становится синей. А тесты - первое мгновение серым, потом IDE помечает их директорию как TestSourceRoot и она становится зеленой.

Как intellij idea автоматически определяет после открытия, какую папку чем нужно пометить?
Эта информация содержится в каком-то файле, или IDE после парсинга сама догадывается, где что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такое понятие в мавен - [стандартная структура проекта](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

IDE "раскрашивает" папки, то есть определяет роль каждой папки в проекте, основываясь на этой структуре. Она нигде ни в каком файле не описана, она всегда такая, если не изменить настройки самого проекта мавен в `pom.xml` файле. Можно изменить где какой вид кода или других ресурсов находится и тогда intellij (да и eclipse) будет использовать измененную конфигурацию.

Comment: Наверное вы правы. Я что-то не нашёл в файлах папки .idea ничего, что могло бы указывать на раскраску папок.

Comment: Если что и хранится в конфигурации само идеи, то это отдельная от мавена конфигурация. Вы можете взять любой maven проект, в котором вообще нет файлов intellij (так исходники в системе контроля версий и хранят ибо разные разработчики пользуются разными IDE) и импортировать, и будет правильно определены папки с кодом, тестами и т.д.